# Prove $x^3 + \sin(3x) = 98$ has a solution in $(0 , 10)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

I believe I need to use the intermediate value theorem for this, but I'm unsure where to go from there. Note that it's a polynomial, so it's going to be continuous.

So I let $f(x)=x^3+\sin(3x)=98$

then we are looking for a number between 1 and 10 such that $f(c)=0$ So I start plugging in numbers and looking for the solution to go from flip from negative to positive or vice versa.

$f(1)= (1)^3+sin(3*1)-98$

$= sin(3)-97$

$= -96.85887$

$f(2) = 2^3 +sin(2) -98 $

$=-90.9092$

.

.

.

$f(5) = 5^3 +sin(5) - 98 $

$= 26.9128442$

And here it's gone positive. Hence proved?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, on the right track. To complete the proof, you just have to tell us which theorem is being used here.

Comment: $97\le 98-sin(3x)\le 99$.  Let $x_1=\sqrt[3] {97}$ and  $x_2=\sqrt[3] {99}$.  $x_1\le x\le x_2$ will give the $x$ you want.

Comment: Yes, your way is correct, but overy complex. Instead just evaluate the function at the interval edges: $0^3+\sin(3x)=0 < 98$ and $10^3+\sin(30)\geq 1000-1 = 999$. Thus by the intermediate value theorem a solution must exists in $(0,10)$.

Comment: “So I let $f(x)=x^3+\sin(3x)=98$.” The $=98$ is not part of the definition of $f$ and shouldn’t be there.

Comment: Also for calculating the solution: Note that we need to have $x^3-1\leq 98 \leq x^3+1$. Thus $x$ must be so that $97\leq x^3\leq 99$. Thus by taking the third root we get $4.594<x<4.627$. By evaluating the $\sin(3x)$ at these bounds we can refine the bounds to $x^3 +0.937\leq 98\leq x^3 + 0.968$. Thus we get $97.032\leq x^3\leq 97.063$ and thus
$$ 4.595\leq x \leq 4.596 $$
We can continue like that to quickly approximate the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you can easily prove more.

If
$f(x)
=x^3+\sin(ax)-b
$
where $b > 0$
($b=98$ here),
since
$-1 \le \sin(ax) \le 1$
so
$x^3-1-b
\le f(x)
\le x^3+1-b
$.

Therefore
if
$x \lt \sqrt[3]{b-1}
$
then
$f(x) < 0$
and if
$x \gt \sqrt[3]{b+1}
$
then
$f(x) < 0$.

Therefore $f(x)$
has a root between these two values.

If your case,
these are
$\sqrt[3]{b-1}
\approx 4.59
$
and
$\sqrt[3]{b-1}
\approx 4.63
$.